# HTML video is always displayed as a square and aspect ratio is not respected

Tags: css, css-selectors, html5-video

I have the following code:

```css
.videoWrapper {
display:flex;
position: relative;
}


.videoWrapper  video {
 width:100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div className='videoWrapper'>
      
    <video controls class="videoPlayer">
        <source src='some-video' type="video/mp4" />
     </video>
</div>
```

I am just trying to show the video in full width of the parent div respecting the aspect ratio of the video, so that the height is adjusted according to the width of the parent div.

But in my case, the video is always shown as a square.

I have played around with object-fill attributes, but nothing changed.

Completely lost here.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Instead of using the `video` element, insert the video into an [iframe Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Answer (score 0):

The `<video>` element doesn't know the actual aspect ratio of your source video until it's loaded and decoded *(after the page itself has rendered)*, so you'll have to use javascript to resize the element once the actual aspect ratio is known. You can try listening for the [`loadedmetadata` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadedmetadata_event), and in that handler resize the element using the videos' [intrinsic width/height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/videoWidth).

If you know ahead of time the aspect ratio of the video maybe you can use `aspect-ratio` rule, or searching around for how to use the `padding-bottom` trick for setting ratio.